# how to update value of header component based content from body component router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, typescript-typings, angular2-webpack-starter

I am working on a shopping site. in that header and footer is fixed in app.component.ts, but router-outlet is dynamic. user login in header and cart tab in header component when I have a login from login component (router-outlet) it's working but in the header, the username is not showing because I have saved some user data in local storage of web browser. data is saving in that but after successful login, it's not showing username from local storage. but when I have refreshed manually then the username is showing. I have many similar issues for like cart item, order etc.

Comment: Post a bit of code

Comment: There are a few solutions for letting `AppComponent` know when something important, such as a login event, occurs. Show us the code that logs in the user

Comment: you have to make use of event emitters in this case in case of sucessfull login emit the value so that the header component can capture that and use that , or make use of shared services

Comment: onSubmit(loginData: UserLogin): void {        this.userService.loginUser(loginData) .then(top => {
                this.loginResponse = top; this.responseMessage = top.message; this.responseStatusCode = top.status;
   if (this.responseStatusCode == 200) {
       this.userDetails = {
                   token: top.data.token,
                   UserId: top.data.UserId
                 }
                    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.userDetails));
                        this.router.navigate(['/home']);window.location.reload();
                    }}})}

Comment: @RahulSingh I have used eventemiter() but it's not working. It's help in parent child component. not in parallel component.

Comment: @VikramBarnwal then you can make use of shared services to pass info to all the components  take a look at this link might help in making shared services https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2 or you can also use ngrx store

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/aJe5SUtFlnpmGXWA5eHk/

Comment: I have uses broadcast and message-event to solve this.   Thanks all for suggestions